# Find a member in an object literal array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to locate a member field within an object literal that is part of an array of items without looping through the entire array? For example:

```
let items = [
   {
      id: "abc",
      name: "john"
   },
   {
      id: "def",
      name: "steve"
   },
   {
      id: "ghi"
      name: "bob"
   }
]
```

If I want to reference the array element where name equals `steve`, is there a way to obtain it but without iterating through all the items and checking the name member?

Comment: No, there is not, unless you know the exact path, as in `items[1].name`. There's no way to search for `steve` without iterating, at least partly

Comment: yes. I want something like a simple method that given just the name returns the index where the name is found to be "steve". Assume that all names are unique.

Comment: What is a "memer"?

Comment: @torazaburo (most likely "member")

Comment: I'm confused, You have 8K of rep, and you are wondering whether we can find an element in an array without looking at all the elements (aka "looping")? Or did you (hopefully) know that of course you would have to loop, but wondered if there something built-in that would do the looping for you? Anyway, I hear that quantum computers can do the kind of thing you might be looking for.

Comment: @torazaburo rep != ability. (Just look at me, I have way too high rep )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without explicitly looping you can use [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to get the object from the array. But anyway you need to compare on some condition to get the desired one. And if you  don't know the index of the item, you need to loop over the array. Instead of explicitly looping you can use built in methods.

```js
let items = [
   {
      id: "abc",
      name: "john"
   },
   {
      id: "def",
      name: "steve"
   },
   {
      id: "ghi",
      name: "bob"
   }
];

const obj = items.find(item => item.name === 'steve');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

> yes. I want something like a simple method that given just the name returns the index

`Array.findIndex` does that, but it still iterates

```js
let items = [
   {
      id: "abc",
      name: "john"
   },
   {
      id: "def",
      name: "steve"
   },
   {
      id: "ghi",
      name: "bob"
   }
]

var index = items.findIndex( item => item.name === 'steve' );

console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you frequently need to get objects by name from the array, you can create a map of name -> object (one time iteration), and then use the map to get the objects:

```js
const items = [
   {
      id: "abc",
      name: "john"
   },
   {
      id: "def",
      name: "steve"
   },
   {
      id: "ghi",
      name: "bob"
   }
];

const itemsMap = items.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.name, o), new Map());

console.log(itemsMap.get('steve'));

console.log(itemsMap.get('bob'));
```